ODBC file configuration
I'm trying to configure the ODBC.ini file
My server is Ubuntu 22.04
How should I configure the odbc.ini file.
These are my configurations and it doesn't work.
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1
UsageCount=1

[MSSQLServer]
Driver = msodbcsql18
Description = Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Server = NEWSQL2019
Port = 1433
Database = NEWSQL2019


"doesn't work" isn't a helpful problem statement; explain why it doesn't work.

Aside... file systems on Linux are usually case sensitive. i.e.: a file named ODBC.ini is different than one named odbc.ini.

The [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server] section should not be in /etc/odbc.ini, it belongs in /etc/odbcinst.ini. Can you confirm that it's already there by cat /etc/odbcinst.ini?

For ODBC Driver for SQL Server there is no Port connection string keyword. The default SQL Server port is 1433 and does not need to be specified. If your instance is listening on a non-default port then you include it in the Server connection string property with a comma separator. e.g.: if your instance is listening on port 3341 then you'd specify Server=YourServerNameOrIpAddress,3341


The [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server] section should not be in /etc/odbc.ini, but in /etc/odbcinst.ini. Can you confirm it's already there via cat /etc/odbcinst.ini?

I confirm that the files are correct and are in lower case. odbc.ini.
this is the content in odbcinst.ini
'
'~$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
'
